# jquery - Enable button if textbox is filled with numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable a button and only enable it when a textbox has text in it that has numbers. This is the current code that I have but it doesn't stop the button from being enabled when it is not numerical text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCalculate').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#txtbox').keyup(function () {
            $('#btnCalculate').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
        })
    });
```

What is required to make the button not be enabled when numerical text is not in the textbox?

Comment: how about parsing the input, something like: ```$('#btnCalculate').prop('disabled', isNaN(parseInt(this.value)) ? true : false);```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it by using a regular expression to make sure the box only contains numbers:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#btnCalculate').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#txtbox').keyup(function () {
    $('#btnCalculate').prop('disabled', this.value.trim().match(/^\d+$/) ? true : false);
  })
});
```

Comment: I think `true` and `false` need to be swapped(?)  Also, this works with whole numbers only, but it's unclear from the OP if real numbers are acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too clear but whole numbers is what I was looking for. This works great and you were right about the true/false @RickHitchcock

Answer (score 0):

```
This may looks very basic solution but you can check length of Textbox to say 
that minimum text should be at least this much number (I use 2 in my example). 
You can change that of course, choose wisely. :-)

//basic solution
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnCalculate').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#txtbox').keyup(function () {
        var strLen = $(this).val().length;
        if (strLen >= 2) { //it can be any number 0 to N
            $('#btnCalculate').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else{
            $('#btnCalculate').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    })
});
```